# Generating Error Message

Tags: validation, jquery, error-handling

This is my original codes for generating error when the telephone number is not entered. it works fine.

```
if ($("shipping_tel")) {
            if ($("shipping_tel").value === "") { 
                ErrorMsg += " - Shipping telephone: Phone Number\n";
                $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'hilight';
            } else {
                $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'lolight';      
            }
        }
```

I need to change something like this..but it don't work

```
if $('ship_shipping').checked = 'TRUE' {

        if ($("shipping_tel")) {
            if ($("shipping_tel").value === "") { 
                ErrorMsg += " - Shipping telephone: Phone Number\n";
                $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'hilight';
            } else {
                $("shipping_tel_label").className = 'lolight';      
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if $('ship_shipping').checked = 'TRUE' {
```

I am assuing ship_shipping is a checkbox?? How about this:

```
if($('ship_shipping').is(':checked')){
   /** your code **/ 
}
```